# What is valid cron on GCP Cloud Scheduler?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a Cloud Scheduler running on GCP and I would like to run with `2/5 * * * 1-5`. This does not really work, it is instead just triggered once per hour, at 4 minutes past the hour for some reason. I know this is non-standard cron but at the same time neither the console or SDK complain about it.

- I wonder what is valid cron for the Cloud Scheduler?
- Is there any way to do what I wish, running it every five minutes after 2 past, i.e. HH:02, HH:07, HH:12 etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short; I simply messed up the cron timing. It works as it should with `2-59/5 * * * 1-5`. This format follows the cron-standard.